# Tab space following \ when using mkdir causing wrong directory created

Tags: shell, unix, makefile

When I use the below script, a [tab] causes mkdir to combine multiple calls together:

---

```
            #Ends with a \[TAB] which screws up bill
            SubTestCase := \
                zack \
                jill \
                jack \
                tom \   

            #bill gets placed in the wrong folder
            #because he directly follows SubTestCase
            TestCases := \
                $(SubTestCase)\
                bill \
                jane

            Test:
                mkdir -p $(addprefix hello/,$(TestCases))
```

---

The above script creates hello\jack, hello\jane, hello\jill, hello\tom, hello\zack,

but weirdly creates "hello\ hello\bill". Is there any mkdir flags, modes, or syntax I can use so that when it reads the "[TAB]" it doesn't create hello\ hello\bill, but rather hello\bill. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it creates "hello/ hello/bill" and not two different directories "hello/<tab>" and "hello/bill", or something like that? But one way or the other, why not just solve the problem by removing the extraneous "\<tab>" which clearly isn't supposed to be there? `make` is only doing what you told it to do, by having an entry at the end of the `SubTestCase` consisting of a (quoted) tab character.

Comment: @Celada I am sure it creates "hello/ hello/bill". I am asking because this is part of a more complex build system, and I basically need a robust solution for mkdir to handle the cases when people add a \[TAB] at the end. If not the only solution is to in fact remove the \[TAB].

Comment: Well, the bottom line is that I would say that if someone makes a syntax error in a Makefile which causes an incorrect action, I would say that the correct solution is to fix the syntax error, not try to defend against it. Whitespace is significant in Makefiles and that's a fact of the language's syntax which Makefile authors need to respect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean by "a TAB"; where is this TAB in the script?

Anyway, you can use the `$(strip ...)` function to get rid of extraneous whitespace:

```
Test:
        mkdir -p $(addprefix hello/,$(strip $(TestCases)))
```